# Does Azure Accelerated Networking also include HTTP traffic, downloads, etc

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, azure, virtual-machines

Does the new Azure Accelerated Networking on NICs increase the speed of HTTP requests?  I keep reading it increases the speed but it looks like between VM in Azure, like file transfers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accelerated networking is at the network card level, it is not protocol specific. If you are communicating between two VM's with accelerated networking then you should be able to get the full 30Gb/s throughput (depending on the size of the machine).

If your communication is for serving a web page to the outside world, then it is going to depend on many more factors, the users connectivity, the distance and number of hops the traffic is travelling etc. The VM will still have a NIC operating at 30Gb/s but the rest of the connection may not support that.

Comment: I understand that, but does AN increase the speed of the current default that is already in place.  I know it wont get the machine to machine, but does it have any increase at all on the protocol level like HTTP?

Comment: The speed of your network connectivity is not really going to be impacted by the protocol you are using. Sending 100MB of HTML data is not really any different to sending 100MB of of SMB data.

Comment: AN improves latency, jitter and CPU usage. It does not modify the maximum throughput your VM can achieve (except on very very very big VMs). Also it is protocol specific: ICMP does not benefit from AN whilst TCP does (I can't recall if UDP did though).